# How can I sort out my many versions of ruby on macOS?

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, rubygems, rbenv

I have serious issues with ruby on my computer. I have the system one, I have the one which can from homebrew, I have one installed as a stand alone version, and I have several installed from rbenv. 
The result of `which -a ruby` is:

```
/usr/local/bin/ruby
/Users/soldenh/.rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

However, `ruby -v` returns:

```
ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x86_64-darwin17]
```

but `Rbenv global` returns:

```
2.4.0
```

and `rbenv local` returns:

```
2.1.9
```

there is also are also 2 brew casks installed one called:

```
ruby@19
```

and the other is called:

```
ruby@22
```

I am using the lastest mac OSX.

Comment: I recommend using [Ruby Version Manager](http://usabilityetc.com/articles/ruby-on-mac-os-x-with-rvm/).

Comment: @TomAranda `rbenv` is generally less intrusive on macOS, but either one should work.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to ditch your Homebrew installed versions and focus on one version manager, such as `rbenv`. The system Ruby will always be there, that's fine. `rbenv local` shows what version your `.ruby-version` file specifies.

Comment: I have been happy with [RVM](https://rvm.io) from El Capitan to Sierra.